# How to change web.config to use a json file that is hosted in another domain

Tags: json, web-config

I'm having a problem when trying to get a JSON file with some font information that is hosted in another domain. It looks like the error is related to Acces-Control-Allow-Origin.

**Error:**
Font from origin '172.12.21.2:323' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:51' is therefore not allowed access.

Can I fix it using my web.config file instead of changes in IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this configuration into a tag system.webServer

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```